# Cannot delete software from Software Center

Tags: software-center, uninstall

I am having the issue that when I want to uninstall software from the Software Center it will allow me to go through the deletion menu, but will not follow through with the deletion (see images). Is there a quick fix to this issue?

Software center menu:

[image: software center menu]

Software deletion menu:

[image: software deletion menu]

Comment: Refresh your window, or exit&restart. The application is working with out-of-date data.

Comment: What is it you intend to show with the images? I cannot see anything that is not normal.